# Can we have a flag for sites with mature content?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, sites

To my horror today, I discovered that StackMobile was happily serving up content from the newest Stack Exchange site. (StackMobile has a cron job that runs daily, updating the list of sites using the API.)

So, to the point of my request - can we please add a flag to the `/sites` route that signals content that might be inappropriate for some users (since Stack Exchange reaches a broad range of users)?

---

**Edit:** after further thought, I remembered that this domain will also show up in `/users/{ids}/associated`. I'm not sure how *that* one can be resolved. Perhaps an app-specific flag can be set indicating whether such content should be exposed to the app.

Comment: What site are you talking about? The newest is Biology? but I agree there are some sites coming along that need such a flag.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot StackExchange doesn't show closed beta sites...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sexuality site was an experiment, [one which failed.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3303/sexuality)

We may revisit this in the future, but for now there's no point in the flag as it's one use case is gone.

Comment: Great - we can revisit this later if another similar site pops up but for now we don't need to worry about it.